# What's the difference in Geas saying it can be removed by Wish?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

The text for [*geas*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/geas) says the following about removing the spell:

> A *remove curse*, *greater restoration*, or *wish* spell also ends it.

However, you can already use *wish* to replicate *remove curse* or *greater restoration* and thus end *geas*.  It seems redundant.

What's the difference if it didn't mention using Wish? Is there a genuine mechanical difference that I'm missing?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is conceivable for a sorcerer to not know of a cleric spell to *wish* for in order to remove *geas*, per [David Coffron’s answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/140081/4563). It’s a good point and I’ve upvoted that answer; it certainly is *a* difference.

But I find it isn’t a very compelling one. After all, not mentioning *wish* would take up less space, and thus save Wizards of the Coast money. I’ve worked in the RPG publishing business—publishers do *not* print things they don’t feel they have to print; it’s expensive. A corner-case like that doesn’t seem to justify the expense.

That difference may well be the only *mechanical* difference between the two approaches, but there are *other* differences between the two that should be considered—are more compelling, in my opinion, for answering the implicit question here—why this way and not the other way?

#### Player approachability

**Players** may not be familiar with *wish* when they get *geas* cast on them. They may not know that *wish* can copy *remove curse* or *greater restoration*. This is a far greater concern for Wizards of the Coast than the sorcerer not knowing about those spells—repetition is a big part of how human beings learn, and for many players, this may not even be a repeat. An accessible ruleset should be directing players to look into things that could be relevant to them when possible.

#### A continued tradition

Notably, this way is how D&D has traditionally handled *wish*—that is, *wish* has traditionally been listed as healing all manner of afflictions, even when those afflictions could be cured through spells *wish* was well capable of emulating. For example, the 3.5e version of *bestow curse* mentions *wish* alongside *remove curse*, which absolutely could have just been copied by *wish*. Longtime D&D players are used to *wish* being mentioned as a solution to all manner of afflictions. Failing to do so could give some of them to incorrect impression that something about *wish* has changed.

#### But most importantly, because *wish* is special

One might well point out that “the traditional approach” doesn’t really address the question but rather just shifts it—it wasn’t *always* the traditional approach, at some point someone first decided to do it this way. Player approachability might well have been the reason for doing so then, but there is another—more fundamental, and I would argue, *important* reason to mention *wish* explicitly when it could just be implied.

That is, a difference between mentioning *wish* explicitly and letting it be implied is that mentioning it explicitly **mentions *wish* explicitly**. This isn’t a means to an end—it is an end in and of itself. Mentioning *wish* explicitly all over the ruleset establishes, and reinforces, that *wish* is something special. In fact, “being special” is arguably *wish*’s *raison d’etre*.

*Wish* is special. Even among 9th-level spells, *wish* stands out. And that is because *wish* solves one critical problem. Sometimes that problem is not having the spell you need. But more often—both in game, and especially in narrative precedent—the purpose of a *wish* is to undo a dire malady. Think about it: when wishes come from a genie, power and wealth are common choices, but genies are *special* because they provide relatively casual access to the power of wishing. Otherwise, when wishes come true, they are usually the result of magic, the universe, divine forces, whatever, responding to some desperate plea—“save her!” “give him back!” and so on.

And that is why one of *wish*’s most important purviews is healing—because removing a deadly affliction, or death, is a huge part of what actually gets wished for. It establishes *wish* as the ultimate solution, the desperate last-ditch attempt to save someone. It comes at a cost, and at a risk, but it will get the job done.

So having afflictions list *wish*, over and over, even when it’s redundant to do so, as a valid solution, means that you keep seeing *wish* in these kinds of circumstances. It means readers can become familiar with the spell even if they never read it. They become aware that *wish* is out there, and that it is special.

Answer (score 19):

### The difference is the cost of *wish*

If a character doesn't know that *greater restoration* or *remove curse* will work, they may cast *wish* to try to ensure that the *geas* spell ends. In this instance it is an option of *wish* that is not to replicate a spell and is subject to this rule:

> The stress of casting this spell to produce any effect other than duplicating another spell weakens you. After enduring that stress, each time you cast a spell until you finish a long rest, you take 1d10 necrotic damage per level of that spell. This damage can't be reduced or prevented in any way. In addition, your strength drops to 3, if it isn't 3 or lower already, for 2d4 days. For each of those days that you spend resting and doing nothing more than light activity, your remaining recovery time decreases by 2 days. Finally, there is a 33 percent chance that you are unable to cast wish ever again if you suffer this stress.

Answer (score 8):

### *Remove curse* and *Greater Restoration* are touch range.

You could hit up to twenty creatures you can see with the *wish* version, as per the second bulleted effect.

> - You allow up to twenty creatures that you can see to regain all hit points, and you end all effects on them described in the *greater restoration* spell.

Either of the first two bulleted effects of *greater restoration* should suffice.

> - One effect that charmed or petrified the target
> - One curse,
>   including the target's attunement to a cursed magic item

Answer (score 0):

### Primary reason might be because you can't normally cast the lower-level spells

If you are playing in a world where there aren't spellcasting services readily available, then you are limited by the spells your party members can cast. The addition of *Wish* closes the loop so that the players know there is a workaround they might not have considered.

- *[Greater Restoration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/greater-restoration)* can usually only be cast by Bards, Clerics, Druids and Celestial Warlocks
- *[Remove Curse](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/remove-curse)* can usually only be cast by Clerics, Paladins, Warlocks, and Wizards
- *[Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)* can usually only be cast by Sorcerers and Wizards

If *Wish* wasn't a choice and you had a sorcerer and no other caster type you wouldn't have a method of removal.

#### Metagaming prevention?

If you don't have someone who can cast *Greater Restoration* or *Remove Curse*, they can still cast *Wish* to either replicate that particular spell or use *Wish* alone (and possibly suffer the penalties for doing so) if they don't actually know that either of the other spells would work.

Comment: I think what the question is saying is that you could use Wish to duplicate Remove Curse or Greater Restoration anyway so that would allow a sorcerer to remove it

Comment: @Sdjz Adjusted my answer to address that. And they'd still need *Wish* in order to cast the other spells, so it remains a necessity.